# How to obtain OLS estimators of the slopes using the deviations from their means

Tags: regression, least-squares, intercept

In my econometric course we were given the exercise to show that the OLS estimators of the slopes can be derived by converting the data to deviations from their means.

Furthermore, I'm also supposed to regress y in deviation form on the independent variables (in deviation form).

Lastly, I'm asked how the OLS estimator of the intercept can be found from the slope estimators.

I don't know how to start. Any hints are appreciated!